# Deserializing JSON with array of different element types using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, geojson, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I want to deserialize GeoJSON with my extension.

GeoJSON has coordinates for lines as

```
{ coordinates: [[longitude1, latitude1], [longitude2, latitude2, optional_altitude2]] }
```

This is extendible beyond altitude. So following is valid GeoJSON coordinates for LineString

```
{ coordinates: [[longitude1, latitude1], [longitude2, latitude2, optional_altitude2, { my_extension: something_something}]] }
```

So, I define my classes as follows:

```
public class GeoJSonCooridnateExtension
{

    /// <summary>Gets type - should be "Feature".</summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "Something", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Something { get; internal set; }
}

public class GeoJSonGeometry
{
    /// <summary>Gets type - should be "Feature".</summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "type", Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public string GeometryType { get; internal set; }

    /// <summary>Gets horizontal (west-east) position.</summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "coordinates", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public List<List<object>> Coordinates { get; internal set; }
}
```

When creating serializer I pass "GeoJSonCooridnateExtension" as "known type".
The deserializer succeeds but puts a generic object in the array and not of the type I created. I tried to use object API to query generic object properties but none were returned. Is it even possible to do it with DataContractJSonSerializer?

See sample JSON below:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",        
    "geometry":
    {
        "type": "LineString",          
        "coordinates":             
        [
            [-35.480741083326052,47.926613991573959, null, {"Something":"my-value"}],
            [-34.355741083326052,58.027854137187823],
            [-27.605741083326055,49.776973283701281]
        ]           
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post a real json instead of trying to describe it?

Comment: Will add real JSON sample - description provides the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: GeoJSonCooridnateExtension is not inheriting from GeoJSonGeometry. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, it's not supposed to! "geometry" has "coordinates" as an array of array. The inner array would contain either double, null or GeoJSonCoordinateExtension. That's why "Coordinates" in GeoJsonGeometry is List<List<object>>